# advance search with php with pagination?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, advanced-search

I have some users with some info like their countery_id, their education_id, their degree_id etc. and I want to fetch them based on this info in a page with pagination.
I know how to do this with `$_GET` but I want my URL to be clean and I want use `$_POST` for send users info and fetch them.
and for pagination I use get method like this , `?pg=1`

The problem is when I send form and fetch users in first page, there is no problem but when I click for second page. I lose my `$_POST` variables and can't fetch second page result.
what is the best answer for this situation?

Comment: I understand you want a clean url but using `$_GET` is the best practice for this, especially if the end user wants to bookmark a page.

Answer (score 1):

Make the next button to be actually part of a form that submits by post.

```
<form method="post" action="page.php?pg=2" id="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="education_id" value="<?=$education_id;?>" />
    <!-- and so on for the rest of the properties -->
    <input type="submit" value="Next" /> 
</form>
```

or you do not want submit button, create the form and put a link like this one somewhere.

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick='$("#myForm").submit()'> Next </a>
```

Edit: As you can see this solution is not elegant, but it will work. Using $_POST is not recommended, $_GET is better because of bookmarking, etc